# Create tags in a structural directive

Tags: angular

I want to implement a lazy loading directive that only loads images (or really anything else) once they come into view. Normally, this would be [simple](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/), but I want to remain semantic and support no-JavaScript browsers (possible with Angular Universal).

To do this, I would use `<noscript><img src="..."></noscript>` when the image is not in view, and `<img src="...">` once the image comes into view (stripping the parent `<noscript>`).

I want my directive to work like this: `<img src="..." lazyLoad>`.

I have the code to perform the showing state (`createEmbeddedView()` and pass the template), but the issue I'm trying to figure out is how to create the `<noscript>` tag.

Here's my code so far:

```
import {Directive, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({selector: "[lazyLoad]"})
export class LazyLoadDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(
            private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
            private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // not shown: create IntersectionObserver and call show() as appropriate
    }

    showing = true;

    private show(show: boolean) {
        if (show && !this.showing) {
            // show the content image
            this.viewContainer.clear();
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            this.showing = true;
        } else if (!show && this.showing) {
            // TODO: <noscript><ng-content></ng-content></noscript>
            // maybe something with createComponent()?
            // ...then call createEmbeddedView() on the created component?
            this.showing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to do this with a component, but I'd prefer to do this with a [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#write-a-structural-directive) for simplicity.